# What sort of object does the appendChild() function belong to?

Tags: javascript, dom

What object does the appendChild() function belong to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A DOM Node/Element.

```
interface Node {
  // NodeType
  const unsigned short      ELEMENT_NODE       = 1;
  const unsigned short      ATTRIBUTE_NODE     = 2;
  const unsigned short      TEXT_NODE          = 3;
  const unsigned short      CDATA_SECTION_NODE = 4;
  const unsigned short      ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE = 5;
  const unsigned short      ENTITY_NODE        = 6;
  const unsigned short      PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE = 7;
  const unsigned short      COMMENT_NODE       = 8;
  const unsigned short      DOCUMENT_NODE      = 9;
  const unsigned short      DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE = 10;
  const unsigned short      DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE = 11;
  const unsigned short      NOTATION_NODE      = 12;

  readonly attribute  DOMString            nodeName;
           attribute  DOMString            nodeValue;
                                                 // raises(DOMException) on setting
                                                 // raises(DOMException) on retrieval
  readonly attribute  unsigned short       nodeType;
  readonly attribute  Node                 parentNode;
  readonly attribute  NodeList             childNodes;
  readonly attribute  Node                 firstChild;
  readonly attribute  Node                 lastChild;
  readonly attribute  Node                 previousSibling;
  readonly attribute  Node                 nextSibling;
  readonly attribute  NamedNodeMap         attributes;
  readonly attribute  Document             ownerDocument;
  Node                      insertBefore(in Node newChild, 
                                         in Node refChild)
                                         raises(DOMException);
  Node                      replaceChild(in Node newChild, 
                                         in Node oldChild)
                                         raises(DOMException);
  Node                      removeChild(in Node oldChild)
                                        raises(DOMException);
  Node                      appendChild(in Node newChild)
                                        raises(DOMException);
  boolean                   hasChildNodes();
  Node                      cloneNode(in boolean deep);
};
```